# Zkoss using template in zhtml

Tags: java, zk

Good day. Here is my zhtml

```
<x:html xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul"
        xmlns:x="xhtml"
        src="/components/public-page-template.html">
  <div viewModel="@id('vm') @init('TestViewModel')">
    <div children="@init(vm.testList)">
      <template name="children">
        <checkbox label="@load(each)"/>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</x:html>
```

And view model

```
public class TestViewModel {
  public List<String> getTestList(){
    return List.of("one", "two", "three");
  }
}
```

I expect to see 3 checkboxes in rendered html, but I get 3 spans

```
<div id="mXBQ2" class="z-div">
  <div id="mXBQ3" class="z-div">
    <span id="mXBQ4" class="z-label">one</span>
    <span id="mXBQ5" class="z-label">two</span>
    <span id="mXBQ6" class="z-label">three</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

No matter what I put inside template I get 3 spans, template is completely ignored. But if change zhtml to zul

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?variable-resolver class="org.zkoss.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver" ?>

<div xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('TestViewModel')">
  <div children="@load(vm.testList)">
    <template name="children">
      <checkbox label="@load(each)"/>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
```

then template is working as expected and I see 3 checkboxes in result html.

How can I make template work in my zhtml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, what you're missing is the fact that the `<template>` element is not a zul component (instead those are [special ZUML elements](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/ZUML/Elements) which control how components are created).
When running your example code I get an exception ... which indicates what's wrong (more or less clearly).

```
org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.DefinitionNotFoundException: 
    Component definition not found: template in [LanguageDefinition: xul/html]
```

Instead you have to declare and use the according [namespace "zk"](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/ZUML/Namespaces) for these special elements (.zhtml files have different parsing rules than .zul files)

```
<x:html xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul"
        xmlns:x="xhtml"
        xmlns:zk="zk"
        src="/components/public-page-template.html">
...
   <zk:template>
   ...
   </zk:template>
```

Besides that I am not sure what the `src` attribute at the root element `x:html` does. In my tests it was plainly rendered to the DOM element, I assume you have your own custom processing handling that.